Page numbering with Fancyfoot overlays the default page numbering
I want to customize the page numbering in my LaTex document. I'm using \fancyfoot{} but it shows up the footer next to the default page numbering. I use \cfoot{} to get rid of default numbering, but it seems to keep its space. See the picture. I want to show only the \fancyfoot footer and it to be centered or righted properly. Aligning to the left works fine.
\documentclass[12, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number

\usepackage{geometry} % Margin and layout
 \geometry{
 includefoot,
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 bottom=25mm
 }


% Número de página en el pie de página
\fancyfoot[R]{Página \thepage \hspace{1pt} de \pageref{LastPage}}





Please always include a compilable test file in your questions, not just a code fragment.

Change the page geometry before your footer:
\documentclass[12, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{geometry} % Margin and layout
 \geometry{
 includefoot,
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 bottom=25mm
 }

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number

% Número de página en el pie de página
\fancyfoot[C]{Página \thepage \hspace{1pt} de \pageref{LastPage}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}



Great! It works! Thanks!!!

@JavierArambarriCalvo You're welcome!
